# Change text output position of PHP

Tags: php, html

I change a variable to `$result` and then do `echo $result`, the result gets displayed at the very first line of the site, is this display position somehow changeable? Like, printing the output of `echo $result` into a little box at the bottom

```
if (isset($_POST['test']))
{
$result = "itwerks";
echo $result;
}
```

HTML Part:

```
<form method="post">
<button name="test">-> Test! <-</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, are you using an MVC framework?

Comment: Why did i got instanly downvoted? There is no reason to, atleast "you" could have told me in the answers or comment why this quesion is bad

Comment: I didn't downvote you but you didn't provide much context for your issue.  Like for example are you using a framework? Is the PHP and HTML on separate pages or on the same page? Where is the PHP located? All of that matters if you're talking about where the text ends up being displayed.

Comment: I use the php and html on the same page (index.php)

Comment: Ok, so the PHP part is at the top of the page? You can just move it to wherever you want to display it.

Comment: It indeed is at the top, but will it change the position when i move the php part?

Comment: YES...it will.  Move it to wherever you want it to display.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in the comments...

Move your PHP down so that it's not at the top of the page.

You can display PHP anywhere on the page.

```
<?php $var = 'This is some text, it is in a PHP variable'; ?>

<body>
    <div>
        <p>
            This is some text, not in PHP        
        </p>
        <p>   
            <?php echo $var //display some PHP here?> 
        </p>
    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
$result = '<div style="position:absolute; bottom:2px;">itwerks</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a HTML-Tag on the body of your document. In the tag you echo the text, e.g. $result. With CSS you can display the HTML-Tag as a box at the bottom.

Comment: Would you tell me how to do this?

Comment: No, because this are basics of web design. You learn them e.g. here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/ http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp